# Cannot move window because the title bar is above the screen

Tags: gui

Sometimes I open a new window in a program (such as a new notebook in Mathematica), and the title bar of the window appears above the screen, so I cannot drag the window around.

What can I do when this happens? Is there a command I can use in the terminal to maximize the window, or to change its location?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Hold down "Alt", left click and hold in the window, and then move the mouse around. That should grab the window and let you move it.

Comment: +1 Thanks! That works. And it's way simpler than I expected.

Comment: Much easier than my prior method:  click on the window and press alt+space to make the window control menu appear.

Comment: Didn't know about alt+space. Perhaps it is time for me to take another look at the keyboard shortcuts (just hold the super key for a bit).

Comment: What to do with windows that captures all the mouse input and keyboard input? For example how do you do that with a virtualbox window? Pressing alt+space, or alt clicks sends the keystrokes to the guest.

Comment: This trick seems to work well for LXDE, what implements this? Is this built in to the X window system itself or is it a DE feature?

Comment: This is no longer accurate. @nealmcb's answer is correct in 2023.

Answer (score 34):

In Gnome 3, the default is to use the `Super` aka `Window` key with mouse drag. In many previous Ubuntu window managers, it was the `Alt` key with mouse drag.  There are a variety of ways to change this keybinding.  See  [How to enable dragging windows with alt-click in gnome 3 / gnome shell - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/428974/how-to-enable-dragging-windows-with-alt-click-in-gnome-3-gnome-shell)